# cannot damage multiple enemies in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
 private void Cross()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("cross");
    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, Firerange2, enemyLayers);

    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
        
        enemy.GetComponent<Enemyhealth>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        enemy.GetComponent<EnemyStuff>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

In that code, the Enemyhealth script gets damaged but the EnemyStuff does not. If I rearrange it like this:

```
 private void Cross()
{
    animator.SetTrigger("cross");
    Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, Firerange2, enemyLayers);

    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {
          enemy.GetComponent<EnemyStuff>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        enemy.GetComponent<Enemyhealth>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
        if (enemy == null)
        {
            return;
        }
       
    }
}
```

the EnemyStuff script gets damaged but enemyHealth does not.
This is my EnemyStuff TakeDamage void:

```
 public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
    currentHealth -= damage;

    // play hurt animaton
    if (damage == 10)
    {    
        animator.SetTrigger("jab");
        
        if (LookAtCharacter.facingRight == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-150, 0));
            
        }
        else if (LookAtCharacter.facingRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(150, 0));
            
        }


    }

    if (damage == 15)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("uppercut");
        if (LookAtCharacter.facingRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(200, 130));
        }
        else if (LookAtCharacter.facingRight == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-200, 130));
        }
        

    }

    if (damage == 20)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("cross");
        if (LookAtCharacter.facingRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(200, 0));
           
        }
        else if (LookAtCharacter.facingRight== true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-200, 0));
           
        }


        
        
    }

    
}
```

this is my Enemyhe take damage void:
public void TakeDamage(int damage)
{
currentHealth -= damage;

```
    // play hurt animaton
    if (damage == 10)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("hurt");

        if (enemyscript.facingRight == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-150, 0));

        }
        else if (enemyscript.facingRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(150, 0));

        }


    }

    if (damage == 15)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("hurt");
        if (enemyscript.facingRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(200, 130));
        }
        else if (enemyscript.facingRight == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-200, 130));
        }


    }

    if (damage == 20)
    {
        animator.SetTrigger("hurt");
        if (enemyscript.facingRight == false)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(200, 0));

        }
        else if (enemyscript.facingRight == true)
        {
            rb.AddForce(new Vector2(-200, 0));

        }
    }
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please add the TakeDamage() function from both EnemyStuff and EnemyHealth script too so that we can get a better idea about what you want to achieve. and btw, your code has to be improved alot otherwise you'll notice a laggy performance if there are multiple enemies..

Comment: How could I improve my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by replacing the line of code above with this:

` private void Cross()
{
animator.SetTrigger("cross");
Collider2D[] hitEnemies = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(attackPoint.position, Firerange2, enemyLayers);

```
    foreach (Collider2D enemy in hitEnemies)
    {

        if (enemy.CompareTag("enemy"))
        {
            enemy.GetComponent<Enemyhealth>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
        }
        else
        { 
            enemy.GetComponent<EnemyStuff>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
        }
        `
```

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are causing your `enemy` to become `null` following either of the following lines:

```cs
enemy.GetComponent<EnemyStuff>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
enemy.GetComponent<Enemyhealth>().TakeDamage(crossdamage);
```

Which you have then chosen as a condition to `return` from your method.

I believe you want to instead use the key word `continue`, in place of `return` so as the next `enemy` in `hitEnemies` is processed.

I'm not sure if it is your own implementation, but having these methods nullify the `enemy` object does not seem like a good idea, since you will only be able to call one of either of your `TakeDamage` methods whilst this is the case.

For you reference:

`return` will cause the executing method to "stop" at it's execution. In the case that the method returns an object, that object must be returned with the keyword.

`continue` will cause the next iteration of the containing loop to be run.

`break` will exit the containing loop.

Comment: It still works the same if I replace it with continue or break.

Comment: Its continue you need, certainly not break. Are you sure that `hitEnemies` contains more than one `Enemy`? Did you check it at run time?

Comment: It normally contains only one enemy. I should probably add that I get a null reference for enemy b if I attack enemy A and if I attack enemy A, I get a null reference for enemy B but enemy A does not get damaged.